# proper interpretation for these notations

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

we have this 2 equations listed below

```
eq 1. δ[n] = u[n] - u[n-1]
eq 2. y[n] = x[n] - x[n+1]
```

Now the question is, 1.) which of the above equation corresponds to a time shift? (a sequence and then we simply shift them forward/backward with respect to the original sequence)?

2.) how is x[n+1] in equation 2 properly interpreted? is it the whole x[n] sequence shifted to the left, or we simply pick a value for n and add 1 to it(so basically we are referring to the value right after x[n])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is a time shift. A backward time shift of the $u$ sequence, for instance, would be $v_n=u_{n-1}$.

The $\delta$ sequence is the [backward difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BackwardDifference.html) of the $u$ sequence; the $y$ sequence is the negative of the [forward difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ForwardDifference.html) of the $x$ sequence.

Both equations are to be understood as holding for each possible value of $n$, which probably means either for all $n\in\Bbb N$, for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, or possibly for all $n\in\Bbb Z$. If, for instance $u_n=n^2$ for $n\in\Bbb N$, so that $u_0=0,u_1=1,u_2=4$, and so on, then $\delta_1=u_1-u_0=1$, $\delta_2=u_2-u_1=3$, and in general

$$\delta_n=u_n-u_{n-1}=n^2-(n-1)^2=2n-1\;.$$